# How to use a function in criteria but for criteria_range in Excel

Tags: excel, function, date, criteria

Hope it is a simple question, I have two columns, A contains dates, B contains numbers.

I want to average `B:B` but only if the date on `A:A` is the first of the month, for example.

So I thought I would do something like this `=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,B:B,DAY=1)` but sadly it doesn't seem to work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVERAGEIFS does not allow the manipulation of the data as you would need.

---

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B1000*(DAY(A1:A1000)=1))/SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(A1:A1000)=1))
```

---

Or as Mayukh Bhattacharya stated:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(DAY(A1:A1000)=1,B1:B1000,""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

**Note:**

Both these formula will work quicker if the references are limited to the data set and not full columns references.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Follow up question, what is the Excel equivalent of Google Sheet's `A2:A`? Meaning from A2 till the end of the column.

Comment: @DanielCohen there is not one.